# How do I reproduce this JOIN with Doctrine 2?

Tags: join, doctrine, doctrine-orm

My join looks like this in sql:

```
   SELECT m.* 
     FROM settings AS s 
LEFT JOIN modules AS m on s.name = m.module 
    WHERE s.value = 1 
      AND s.category = 'module_status'
```

I cannot figure out how to reproduce this in Doctrine 2.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here are my entities:

```
namespace Entities;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Modules
 *
 * @Table(name="modules")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\Modules")
 */
class Modules
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $module
     * @Column(name="module", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $module;

    /**
     * @var string $label
     * @Column(name="label", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @var string $package
     *
     * @Column(name="package", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $package;

    /**
     * @var string $path
     *
     * @Column(name="path", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @var float $version
     *
     * @Column(name="version", type="float", nullable=false)
     */
    private $version;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getModule() {
        return $this->module;
    }

    public function getLabel() {
        return $this->label;
    }

    public function getPackage() {
        return $this->package;
    }

    public function getPath() {
        return $this->path;
    }

    public function getVersion() {
        return $this->version;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setModule($module) {
        $this->module = $module;
    }

    public function setLabel($label) {
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    public function setPackage($package) {
        $this->package = $package;
    }

    public function setPath($path) {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function setVersion($version) {
        $this->version = $version;
    }


}



namespace Entities;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Settings
 *
 * @Table(name="settings")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\Settings")
 */
class Settings
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string $category
     *
     * @Column(name="category", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var text $value
     *
     * @Column(name="value", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $value;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getCategory() {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory($category) {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need an association configured between the Settings and Modules entities. I'm assuming the relationship between the two is many-to-many:

```
Class Modules
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Settings", inversedBy="modules")
     * @JoinTable(name="modules_settings")
     */
    private $settings;
}

Class Settings
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Modules", mappedBy="settings")
     */
    private $modules;
}
```

Then your query syntax would look like this:

```
$qb->select('s', 'm')
   ->from('Entities\Settings', 's')
   ->leftJoin('s.modules')
   ->where('s.value = 1');
```

I can't tell what's going on in your AND clause, but if what you have is correct, then you simply add this line to the end of your query:

```
->andWhere('s.category = m.status');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have two tables: Module and Settings.  The module table has all the info about the modules (name, version, system path, etc).  The settings table has infor about system settings, in particular, the installation status.  In the settings table there is only one entry for each module.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.  This is what the query ended up being:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select('m')
   ->from('Entities\Modules', 'm')
   ->leftJoin('m.settings', 's')
   ->where('s.value = :enabled')
   ->andWhere('s.category = :moduleStatus')
   ->setParameter('moduleStatus', 'module_status')
   ->setParameter('enabled', 1)
   ->getQuery();
```

This is how I configured the modules entity:

```
/**
* @OneToOne(targetEntity="Entities\Settings")
* @JoinColumn(name="module", referencedColumnName="name")
*/
private $settings;
```